# can view not extend "application/application.html.erb" in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

As we all know, in `ruby on rails`, all views extends from `application/application.html.erb`, most of the time this is great, such as the `application.html.erb` as follow:

```
<html>
<head></head>

<body>

<%= render 'layouts/header' %>
<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

I do not need the write the same code in every view again, but sometimes, just on view is special, this view is different from the view, such as I do not want to add `<%= render 'layouts/header' %>` in this view.

Maybe a parameter will just help me in this situation, but I want to know if any view is able to not extend from `application/application.html.erb`?

Comment: I have just posted an article relating to this, may be you would want to take a look: http://alma-connect.github.io/techblog/2015/02/layout-and-rendering-in-rails.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Views don't 'extend from' `application.html.erb`, they use it as a default layout. You can change it, of course, using `layout` method in controller (or `layout` option in `render` method), like this:

```
# this changes the default layout in every views of `AdminController` (and all other controllers that inherit from `AdminController`):
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  layout :admin
  # ...
end
# this changes the layout of specific action:
class SomethingController < ApplicationController
  # ...
  def some_action
    # ...
    render layout: :some_layout
  end
end
```

Here's the reference:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html